# spring concurrencyFilter behaves different on different tabs for different OS'

Tags: session, web-applications, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0.7 on a project at work. Our application site can be reached via redirection from different sites. We use concurrency filter and a session authentication strategy.

Situation 1:
If you reach the site from a referer in Firefox, and then you reach our site from a different referer in another browser say Chrome, your session in Firefox is destroyed, and you can work normally in Chrome.

Situation 2:
The interesting part is this: my workstation is Ubuntu and when i try to reach from a referer in a tab, then try to reach from another referer on a different tab, older session is discarded again and I have to login and etc. This behaviour is same like the above paragraph.

Situation 3:
I try again from my Ubuntu desktop, and reach the application site from same referrer in different tabs. This time my previous session id is overwritten, and the flow got mixed up because of this.

Situation 4:
On Windows systems by the way, if i access separately from different referrers to the application from different tabs of a same browser, my sessions got mixed up, sessions are just overwritten and the actions done on the application get mixed. Same behaviour as Situation 3.

My intention is to get rid of situation 4, and configure the security system to work as Situation 2. Can I do this with spring security?

Comment: Generally if you use different tabs in a browser they will share the same session. This isn't something that Spring Security has any control over. If you use a different process (not just a tab or window) you will get a new session. Your question really needs a bit more technical detail in terms of what you observe (i.e. concrete details on sessions being overwritten, discarded, mixed up etc). Also, what do you mean by a referer here? The referer header should be irrelevant.